# Web API, How to Override JSON Serialization For Specific DataType?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have bunch of TimeSpan properties in response from Web API. By default JSON serializer includes decimal values of seconds as well in response. E.G. `08:30:00.000909` These micro-seconds values are not needed in response.

> Is it possible to override JSON serializer so that it could skip out
>   milli/micro-second components in the serialized JSON response?

Comment: Have you looked at the callbacks available during serialization/deserialization ? Perhaps you can parse out the data you don't want using these callbacks ? http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use custom serializer for your Web API
http://tinymission.com/post/custom-serialization-for-json-properties-in-web-api

Or before you convert your DTO to Model, you can use Custom Date and Time Format Strings.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx